Whats the way to manage a canvas size in photoshop?
I am not a pro with Photoshop, I have created a banner image in resolution 1349x578 px
Sharing the image below,

But now I want this in a resolution of 1920w x 822h

What I did is, I copied and pasted each and every elements in another new file with the same dimensions mentioned above.

But I think that is not a right way to achieve this. Can someone please give me any other way to do this.

Probably the easiest way is to resample the image using Image > Image Size.

I would just change the canvas size to the new size and Save As.. a new file. then adjust elements for the new size.

@Scott this is what I did. But thanks guys

Thank you @BillyKerr
